# Using proxy in non-browser applications

Tags: proxy

My college uses a proxy server to provide internet. I am able to access internet on  the browser very well and apps like Skype are automatically connected when I login into my browser.
But some apps show error in connecting.
In Windows Store (of Windows10) I am able to open the store but while downloading it shows an error code of 0x800704CF.

Also I am not able to access the internet in the terminal of my virtual machine - Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (I am able to access it in its browser). I get following errors:

While trying

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the error

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80
(2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP:
2001:67c:1562::19 80]
```

And while trying

```
python get-pip.py
```

(after downloading get-pip.py)(to install pip)
I get the error:

```
 Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None))
after connection broken by
'NewConnectionErro ('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedH
TTPS Connection object at 0x7f7451ef1f10>: Failed to establish a new
connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/pip/
```

I have tried to apply the proxy settings on terminal (in Linux) as:

```
 export http_proxy={proxy IP they provided}
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For apt you have to provide Configuration

- [proxy conf for apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489852/proxy-authentication-with-terminal-ubuntu-14-04)

For pip you can use command line arguments
`pip install --proxy user:password@proxyserver:port <package>`